# Разница по времени выполнения тестов при Run и Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, юнит-тесты, nunit

Visual Studio 2015, NUnit 3.

Имеются несколько интеграционных тестов. 
При Debug запуске тест отрабатывает 3-5 минут, как и должен.
При Run тест выполняется за 10 секунд, хотя показывает, что тест зелёный.

В тестируемых компонентах присутствует асинхронность и работа с Ms SQL.
В чем может быть проблема или хотя бы в какую сторону копать?

Comment: в релизе оптимизатор может выкинуть код, который ни на что не влияет

Comment: Стоит добавить пример кода теста

Answer (score 3):

При запуске в режиме без Debug оптимизатор старается хранить переменные регистрах процессора, в том время как в режиме Debug для облегчения получения значений переменных они хранятся в оперативной памяти.

В этом можно убедится, если в настройках проекта поставить галочку на "Выполнять оптимизацию". Тогда при запуске Debug вы не сможете получить значение переменных.

Так же оптимизатор может проводить дополнительные оптимизации, например foreach заменять на for, удалять неиспользуемые переменные и т д...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446027/debug-vs-release-performance